How to get a ShareLink that only loads the file URL to share when needed
I have a method which bundles a bunch of things together into a zip file for sharing. I want to expose this in SwiftUI however if I do it like
 ShareLink(item: zipUpUsefulThings()

I am wastefully doing the IO for zipping things into a folder when not needed. I could use a custom Transferable and generateReport to delay computation till it's actually being shared but that only works for strings. If I put a url in the share item it is calculated immediately.
Here is the code
ShareLink(item: ZipLog(), preview: .init("Subscription Debug Log")) {
    Label("Share DebugFiles", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
                    }.controlSize(.regular).buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)

struct DebugLogShare: Transferable {
    func generateLogs() -> URL {
        return Debug.createZipOfLogs()!
    }

    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        ProxyRepresentation { report in
            generateLogs()
        }
    }
}

In this example Debug.createZipOfLogs is called the moment the share button scrolls into view and again when user clicks share. This is undesirable.
Is there any way to avoid this and have a share item that only calculates its URL at the last possible moment?

"But that only works for strings" No it doesn't. Please show your attempt, and demonstrate how it zips things before you share. After you do that, I will reopen.

@Sweeper thanks for bringing that one up. I had seen it. It didnt make it very clear that a URL could work in place of a string for the generateLogs method. I assumed it was some API but I am guessing that is just a name they made up.

Anywho have updated question. Does not work with the code in the (hopefully) formerly duplicated question.

For file URLs, it is more appropriate to use a FileRepresentation rather than ProxyRepresentation.
struct ZipLog: Transferable {
    func generateLogs() -> URL {
        print("Generating URL...")
        return URL.documentsDirectory.appending(path: "foo.txt")
    }
    
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        FileRepresentation(exportedContentType: .utf8PlainText) { logs in
            SentTransferredFile(logs.generateLogs())
        }
    }
}

ShareLink(item: ZipLog(), preview: .init("Subscription Debug Log")) {
    Label("Share DebugFiles", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
}
.controlSize(.regular).buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)

Now, "Generating URL..." will be printed after you select a share option, like "Save to Files".
I'm not sure about other share options, but "Save to Files" only works if you also set these Info.plist keys to YES:

LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace
UIFileSharingEnabled

